# JavaScript: Change an Image Weekly

Tags: javascript

How can I change an image once a week using JavaScript?

Comment: Take a look at the Javascript Date object, although I would think this would be better executed on the server-side.

Comment: Agree with Lazarus. If you really want to do it client-side, you could use a cookie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array();
arr=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var img=getCookie("imag");
if (img!=null && img!="")
  {
    document.getElementById("img").src=img+".jpg"; 
  }
else 
  {
    var rd=Math.random()*1000;
    rd=String(rd);
    rd=rd.substr(6,1);

    setCookie("imag",rd,30);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
<img src="" id="img" height="87" />
</body>
</html>
```

set ten image in same folder with html file numberd as 1.jpg and 2.jpg ..... 9.jpg

Comment: but then is it compulsory to use PHP for doing it?

Comment: if you use php , why don't use it in your problem , but you can generate images by for loop

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use Javascript to get the weeknumber and use that number to pick an appropriate image. If you want a different image for each week of the year, for example, you could have an image like image03.png for week 3.

However, I recomment doing this serverside to have the image already decided when delivering the webpage so the user doesn't experience a delay in having the image appear.